# С++ поиск ошибок. Зашифровать и расшифровать текст по условию

Tags: c++, массивы, шифрование, динамические-массивы

Условие:

Написать программу на языке С++, в которой создать:

- строку символов и заполнить ее;
- байтовый массив (элементы массива имеют тип char), предназначенный для хранения закодированной строки.

Каждый символ строки закодировать по следующему правилу: первые 8 наиболее часто встречающихся символов

кодируются 0 битом и следующим за ним трехбитовым ко-дом (000 … 111), остальные символы – 1 битом и следую-щим за ним ASCII кодом символа (8 бит). Полученный код записать в байтовый массив. В итоге в байтовом массиве должны быть записаны последовательно один за другим ко-ды всех символов строки. Определить коэффициент сжатия. Вывести на экран элементы байтового массива в двоичном виде.

Декодировать битовую последовательность, содержа-щуюся в байтовом массиве. Результаты декодирования за-писать в файл.

Реализовать в программе функции, необходимые для решения поставленной задачи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что мне удалось сделать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <bitset>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void del(char el[], int j, int &size) {
    for(int i = j; i < size - 1; i++)
        el[i] = el[i + 1];
    size--;
}

void uniq(char el[], int &size) {
    int i, j;
    char elem;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        elem = el[i];
        for(j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
          if(elem == el[j]) {
                del(el, j, size); j--;  
      }
    }
  }
}

struct table{
  char text;
  int num;
  char* code;
};

bool asort(table l, table r) { return l.num > r.num; }

table *gen(char mass[]){
  int size = strlen(mass);
  char str[size];
  strcpy(str, mass);
  uniq(str, size);
  table *codetable;
  codetable = new table[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    codetable[i].text = str[i];
    codetable[i].num = count(mass, mass+size*10, str[i]);
  }
  sort(codetable, codetable+size, asort);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      if (i < 8){
      bitset<4> a(i);
      codetable[i].code = strdup(a.to_string().c_str());
    }else{
      bitset<8> b((int)str[i]);
      codetable[i].code = strdup(("1" + b.to_string()).c_str());
    }
  }
  return codetable;
}

char* encode(char mass[], table gen[]) {
  int size = strlen(mass);
  char* res;
  res = new char[size];
  cout << "Как надо зашифровать:"<< endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
      if (mass[i] == gen[j].text){
        res[i] = *gen[j].code;
        cout << gen[j].code << " ";

      }
    }
  }  
  cout << endl;
  return res;
}

char* decode(char* crypt[], table gen[], int size){
  char* res;
  res = new char[size];
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
      if (gen[j].code == crypt[i]) {
        res[i] = gen[j].text;
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
  char mass[] = "Yeah baby, I like it like that You gotta believe me when I tell you";
  //char mass[] = "To have to go to bed by day?";
  int size = strlen(mass);
  table *code;
  code = new table;
  code = gen(mass);
  cout << "Строка: \n" << mass << endl;
  cout << "Таблица шифрования:" << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    cout << code[i].text << " "<< code[i].code << endl;
  }
  char* encrypt;
  encrypt = new char[size];
  encrypt = encode(mass, code);
  cout << "То, что выдает encode:" << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout << encrypt[i] << " ";
  }
  //char* decrypt = decode(encrypt, gen);
 //cout << decrypt == mass ? "True" : "False";
  return 0;
}
```

Вопросов несколько:

1. В `table *gen(char mass[])` (строка 37-59) содержится код `uniq(str, size)`.Каким образом можно узнать количество элементов, которые выводит этот участок кода? (Необходимо в строках 43-49 использовать размер этой выборки, а не всю длину массива `size`).
2. как передать в `res[i]`(строка 69) всё содержимое `gen[j].code`, а не только первый символ?

Comment: Код лучше все-таки выкладывать сюда.

Comment: начнем с того, что вы не выполнили первое условие: не написали программу на языке C++

Comment: Я не очень понел как кодировать нужно. Покажите пожалуйста пример, каким должен быть закодированный  символ (01100001)  в случаи, если встречается наиболее часто и в обратном случаи

Comment: Добавил информацию

Comment: вот это другое дело...

Answer (score 0):

Вы так старались при записи вопроса, что я не смог удержаться и сделал для вас свой вариант(все написано на языке С++). Честно говоря не думал об оптимизации, но думаю и так сойдет:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
using Par = std::pair<char, int>;
struct Cmp {
    bool operator ()(Par p1, Par p2) {
        return p1.second > p2.second;
    }
};
unordered_map<char, string>
info_from_string(const string& s)
{
    unordered_map<char, int > m;
    int sz = s.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        m[s[i]]++;
    }
    //обьект m теперь содержит таблицу символов и их количества в строке
    //нам нужно получить 8  отсорированных (по количеству)  элементов
    vector<Par> v(m.begin(), m.end());
    partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + 8, v.end(), Cmp());
    //теперь закодируем символы в строке
    bitset<8> bs;
    string str;
    sz = v.size();
    char c;
    //создадим таблицу символ/кодировка
    unordered_map<char, string> res;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        c = v[i].first;
        if(i < 8)  //если символ из топ 8
        {
            static int k{}; //каждый следующий символ имеет значение
            bs = k;
            str =  bs.to_string();
            //как вы сказали, берем только последные 4 бита, хотя, 
            //по  хорошему, нужно брать  на 1 больше, чем помещается 
            // v[0].first (число, имеющее значение наибольшего количества символа
            str = str.substr(4); 
            ++k;
        }
        else {
            bs = c;
            str = "1" + bs.to_string();
        }
        res.emplace(make_pair(c, str));
    }
    return res;
}
// теперь создадим таблицу кодировка/символ
unordered_map<string, char> mm;
const string
code(const string& s) //кодировка
{
    string str;
    auto m = info_from_string(s);
    for (auto p : m)
        mm.emplace(make_pair(p.second, p.first));
    for (char c : s)
        str += m[c] + ' ';
    return str;
}
const string
decode(const string& s) // раскодировка
{
    istringstream is(s); //чтобы работать с каждым словом
    string ss, str;
    while (is >> ss)
        str += mm[ss];
    return str;
}

int main()
{        
    const string s("we need to write code in C++. Pass a string to a function"),
                  scode(code(s)), sdecode(decode(scode));
    //показать кодировку
    cout << scode << endl << endl;
    //показать раскодировку
    cout << sdecode;
    return 0;
}
```

Если написать соотвтествующий класс, то все будет выглядеть гораздо проще и короче, но в вашем задании говорится о реализации функций.

Comment: Интересно, чем же соответствующий класс так улучшит этот код? Хотелось бы посмотреть на такую версию, потому что мне пока кажется, что всё, что изменится, так это то, что все эти функции просто переместятся в класс и станут его методами; а вызываться будут через объект, а не напрямую

Comment: Почему `code` возвращает строку? Должна возвращать массив байт с упакованными битами внутри.